# Spawn process on remote host in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, remote-server, child-process

I have a simple Node server that serves a page with a button. On click that button needs to execute a command on a remote host. When the command finishes, the output should then be given to the response of the function and shown in the html.

Currently this is the server code:

```
app.use(logger("combined"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/connect', function (req, res) {
    var spawn = require('cross-spawn-async');
    var mpiProc = spawn('ssh','pi@raspi2','"ls"', { stdio: ['pipe','pipe',2,'pipe'] });

    var grid = "...8.1..........435............7.8........1...2..3....6......75..34........2..6..";
    str = "";
    mpiProc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        str = data.toString();
        res.write('data: ' + JSON.stringify({ msg : str }) + '\n\n');
        // Output       
    });

    mpiProc.on('close', function(code) {
        res.end(str);
        // Script exit code
    });

    mpiProc.on('error', function(code) {
        res.end('stderr: ' + code);
        // Script exit code
    });
}) 
    require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

As you can see the following call tries to execute the 'ls' command on a remote host:

```
var mpiProc = spawn('ssh','pi@raspi2','"ls"', { stdio: ['pipe','pipe',2,'pipe'] });
```

But this doesn't return anything, while executed from the server directly from terminal, it returns the list of directory content. To test if the command works this way with a spawn I tried doing this:

```
var mpiProc = spawn('ls', { stdio: ['pipe','pipe',2,'pipe'] });
```

Which returns what I expected, the list of directory content on the server.
So how can I create a pipe to a remote host to execute a command and then store the result of the command on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument passed to `spawn()` is an array of arguments. Also, you don't need to manually quote your arguments. This should work:

```
spawn('ssh', ['pi@raspi2', 'ls'], { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 2, 'pipe'] });
```

Lastly, if you want more programmatic (and lightweight) control over the ssh connection, there is the [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module (or any of the modules that build on top of it), which does not use child processes.